# Installed and used Ubuntu Successfully, still takes me to black "install ubuntu" screen upon restart

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, usb, usb-installation

Note: I am still a novice with computers.

I have an Acer Aspire E5, with Windows 10.

I just installed Ubuntu from a USB (somewhat) successfully. Had a hell of a time, I think it is because I did not properly boot my computer before installing? It kept taking me back to the black screen upon restart. Nonetheless, I do now have Ubuntu running properly.. I am able to use it with all of its full features, my data and settings continue to be saved, all of that good stuff.

Yet, every time I restart my machine, it takes me back to the original black screen asking me if I want to try Ubuntu, Install Ubuntu, etc. or says "cannot find bootable device" if my thumbdrive isn't in.

When I go back to the boot menu from this black screen, I can select my own hard drive rather than USB.. from which it will take me straight to my log in screen for Ubuntu, when I log in all of my files and settings still in tact as it should be.

Why does the black screen come up still when I restart, if the system (in some form) is still running properly?

I really appreciate any help here. What is the problem, and how can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: First off, make sure the installation USB is removed after successful install. If that fails then change the BOOT order, which normally should go through all options and not seeing your USB should boot from HDD, or SSD...

Comment: Still USB is connected with your system?

Comment: When I disconnect USB, Ubuntu continues to work until I restart.. in which I am offered the black screen again. I am currently trying to figure out how to access the BIOS menu on my acer aspire e5 to change the boot priority, as I believe the USB is currently saved as first...

Comment: For aspire laptops bios key will be F2 or F12. If you are not able access bios remove HDD then press F2 or F12 key.

Comment: I was able to configure the BIOS settings, and my hard drive is indeed the first priority.. yet still, won't startup without the USB stick in it. Any ideas on what the problem is? Thanks

Comment: where did you install your bootloader while ubuntu installation. It could be that you installed it on your thumb drive

Answer (score 1):

From BIOS change the boot device priority to have you hdd/ssd on top. You might have changed the order for installing ubuntu from the thumb drive and for some reason it might not have switched back when you removed the drive.

After some talking and thinking, I think that you might have selected a wrong partition to install boot loader while installing ubuntu and thus it's not running without the thumb drive.

[Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) is a good package that might help you in this case.

If that does not work you can go [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows). The page however seems to be down right now, but it has helped me a lot of time and hopefully will be up, after they fix the problem.

After coming to know that the boot partition was installed on the thumb drive (i.e. grub on thumb drive)

Do the following:

1. Boot up ubuntu however you can.
2. Open terminal
3. Run `sudo grub-install /dev/sdXY` where you replace X with drive letter i.e a, b, ... and Y with partition number i.e. 1, 2,...

Comment: Good idea.. I checked the boot device priority and the HDD was indeed first.. so I am still not sure what the problem is here...

Comment: can you run `sudo fdisk -l` and paste the results

Comment: Yes, the result is way too many characters long.. which part do you want to see?

Comment: all of it. wait I'll try to find how to start a chat

Comment: ah can't chat with you, you apparently need 20+ points to chat

Comment: I appreciate your help.. could I email it to you?

Comment: where did you install your bootloader while ubuntu installation. It could be that you installed it on your thumb drive

Comment: you can post it in you question as `output of {command}` and then the output

Comment: yes.. would it have anything to do with the partition? My computer has the scan disk as the master boot record

Comment: It has everything to do with that problem, if you have selected the thumbdrive as the MBR, it explains everything, you need to change it

Comment: Thank you!! Any advice on resources where I could learn how to change it?

Comment: The second link that I gave will help

Comment: Look at the answer now